# char + String giving strange result

Tags: java, string, char, concatenation

Question:
Given a string, take the first 2 chars and return the string with the 2 chars added at both the front and back, so "kitten" yields"kikittenki". If the string length is less than 2, use whatever chars are there.

```
    front22("kitten") → "kikittenki"
    front22("Ha") → "HaHaHa"
    front22("abc") → "ababcab"
```

My answer:

```
public String front22(String str) {
    if(str.length() > 2) {
        char first = str.charAt(0);
        char second = str.charAt(1);
       return first + second + str + first + second;
    }  
    return str + str + str;
}

    Results:
    Expected                           Run             results
    front22("kitten") → "kikittenki"   "212kittenki"   X        
    front22("Ha") → "HaHaHa"           "HaHaHa"        OK       
    front22("abc") → "ababcab"         "195abcab"      X        
    front22("ab") → "ababab"           "ababab"        OK       
    front22("a") → "aaa"               "aaa"           OK       
    front22("") → ""                   ""              OK       
    front22("Logic") → "LoLogicLo"     "187LogicLo"    X
```

So where are the numbers i.e. 212, 195 and 187 that are in front of my output are coming from? I am new to JAVA. Sorry if this is something very simple or basic that I don't know.I know I could have done it the following way, but just want to know what's going on with my first answer.

```
public String front22(String str) {
    if(str.length() > 2){
    return str.substring(0,2) + str + str.substring(0,2);
}

  return str + str + str;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the ascii sum of the characters: 
For your first case, `i` has ascii `105` and `k` has ascii `107` so their sum is `212`. 
Try `str.subString(0, 2)` instead of adding the `char` variables.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to know where the numbers are coming from and why. This explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your method tries to sum up those values like integers. you have to convert the first item to a string to avoid this issue, or use a StringBuilder.

```
'L' = 76
'o' = 111
76 + 111 = 187
187 + "String" = "187String"
```

**Solution 1:**

return Character.toString(first) + second + str + first + second;

**Solution 2:**

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(first);
builder.append(second);
builder.append(str);
builder.append(first);
builder.append(second);
return builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's interpreting them in their character integer form and adding them.

You can fix this by making sure you are returning a String:

```
return "" + first + second + str + first + second;
```

Or:

```
return (String) (first + second + str + first + second);
```

Comment: It's casting it to a String just like the first one is, except the first one is being implicitly cast and the second is being explicitly cast. I am not sure of the nitty-gritty details of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is happening. The return statement is trying to add the first two characters and after that the string comes into picture and hence the last two are properly interpreted as characters and added to the string while for the first two their ascii sum is added at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

From type conversion to byte. The first plus operation will be treated as numeerical operation (char codes will be used as input) which will give you the number, which later will be converted to string to be appended to following string. If you start your statemetn with "" all + operation will be treated as concatenation.